# Will all or most browsers be able to render a URL with an emoji after backslash? 

Tags: url, cross-browser, emoji

```
http://www.example.com/here-it-is-
```

My Rails site seems to be fine with it.

Will all browsers render this properly? Never saw this before.

Comment: Live example: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%98%83](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%98%83)  (`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/☃`)

Comment: God this sounds like a horrible idea. Hey did you see the latest cat video? Check it out, go to www, dot poop emoji, middle finger emoji, eggplant emoji...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all browsers will render that properly, it depends on if they support Unicode in their address bars. Some browsers only support percent-sign encoded Unicode, and will even convert it in the backend (while it may or may not show the user the Unicode address).

As to specifically emojis, as long as the browser supports the version of Unicode that has the emoji you want, it should work. You can see browser/device Unicode support here: http://unicode.johnholtripley.co.uk/

Comment: url not longer working, do you have an alternative site?